# Ninject factory method with input parameter to determine which implementation to return

Tags: ninject, factory-pattern

I am trying to find a way to have a factory class / method that would take in an object or some kind of identifier (string or type) then based off the input parameter determine which implementation of the interface to create and return.

how do I setup my factory method and register the dependency for the interface? following is what I have roughly.

```
public class ISampleFactory
{
   public ISample GetSample(Type type)
   {
      // do something here to return an implementation of ISample
   }
}


public class SampleA : ISample
{
   public void DoSomething();
}

public class SampleB : ISample
{
   public void DoSomething();
}

public interface ISample
{
   void DoSomethin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ninject Contextual Bindings Documentation:
You can either use Named Bindings:

```
this.Bind<ISample>().To<SampleA>().Named("A");
this.Bind<ISample>().To<SampleB>().Named("B");
```

or a conditional binding with any of the already available extensions or write your own:

```
this.Bind<ISample>().To<SampleA>().When(...);
this.Bind<ISample>().To<SampleB>().When(...);
```

see https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: How do I use contextual binding with the factory I have above? i don't want to take any dependency on Ninject in my implementation and factory class.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You would need at least an abstract layer. For the above the implementation itself is very simple: `IResolutionRoot.Get<ISample>("A")`.
Whats the benefit of not having a dependency onto ninject?

Comment: just as a general practice we have in our shop to not create implementation that depend on or specific to a DI container implementation.

Comment: In that case you can create an abstraction interface `INamedFactory.CreateNamedInstance<T>(string name)" and create the ninject implementation `NinjectNamedFactory.CreateNamedInstance<T>` = `IResolutionRoot.Get<T>(name)`. You will at least need that ninject specific class - as you do need your ninject specific mappings which you can't use with another DI as well.